# Find the output of?

Tags: c, pointers

It is a question given in one of our placement Exams.
 explain the output of the following code...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i = 320;
   char *ptr = (char *)&i;
   printf("%d", *ptr);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++, let alone C++11.

Comment: @Hari Krishna Singireddi It is interesting what is the "placement Exams"?

Comment: @LeFou the question  is, find the output of the given code...

Comment: @Hari: The output _when_? On what system? On what day of the week? The program does not have well-defined standard-mandated semantics.

Comment: @ Vlad,   I mean on-campus Recruitments...

Comment: @Hari Krishna Singireddi Oh, I would not pass the exam....

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, Yes,  It's definitely a stupid exam this was the only information given to us....

Answer (score 6):

You will get the numeric value of the "first" byte that makes up the `int` with value 320.

The precise output depends on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your platform:

- Little-endian output: `64`
- Big-endian output: `0`
- Middle-endian output: god knows

Here are the octet-components of a 32-bit `int` on a little-endian, [two's-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) system:

- octet #0: `0x40`
- octet #1: `0x01`
- octet #2: `0x00`
- octet #3: `0x00`

*(An octet is an 8-bit byte. Your platform* probably *has octets as `char`, however more exotic platforms, with larger `CHAR_BIT` values, do exist.)*

Comment: Or if sizeof int is 1 then the value of first char is 320...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala https://stackoverflow.com/q/50930891/560648

Comment: `CHAR_BIT != 8`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, it's possible (e.g. on Crays `sizeof(int)` was 1)